# ValurError when creating a Pygame surface in a class

Tags: class, pygame, pygame-surface

for some reason, this code doesn't work and for the life of me I can't figure out

```
import pygame as py

py.init()
py.font.init()

c_size = 35

monaco = py.font.SysFont("monaco", int(round(c_size * 1.4)))


class Button(object):
    def __init__(self,title):

        self.title = title

        self.width = monaco.size(self.title)[0]
        self.height = monaco.size(self.title)[1]
        
        self.surf = py.Surface(int(self.width), int(self.height))

stop = Button("Stop")
```

Raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yonatanmitzna/Desktop/hiuoho.py", line 21, in <module>
    stop = Button("Stop")
  File "/Users/yonatanmitzna/Desktop/hiuoho.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.surf = py.Surface(int(self.width), int(self.height))
ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)
```

I tried to test the type of the values going into the py.Surface command, and they are both int! no clue why this doesn't work.

Comment: the first parameter to `Surface` needs to be a tuple but you're passing width and height separately. Wrap them in parentheses instead.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) must be a tuple with the size of the surface, instead of 2 separate arguments:

<s>`self.surf = py.Surface((int(self.width), int(self.height)))`</s>

```py
self.surf = py.Surface((int(self.width), int(self.height)))
```